# Is there a published list of particles that can be produced from the fundamental particles in the Standard Model?

Tags: standard-model

I read an article that has made me curious to ask if there is a list of all the possible particles that can be generated by the fundamental particles in the Standard Model.   Here is the article 
http://www.sci-news.com/physics/cern-new-particles-06460.html

I recall reading that back in the 60's and 70's lots of particles were discovered that eventually turned out to be combinations of the Standard Model particles. A truly amazing accomplishment, I am still awe struck.

But I always assumed this works in reverse so that scientists also can work mathematical calculations that predict particles and then they are observed.  I believe this case applies to the article ?

Just curious now if there is a laundry list or it's just one of those things that it's like counting the integers , the Standard Model will never run out of particles that can fit it.

Comment: Indeed, all observed particles so far, including those of you article, are anticipated/predicted by the standard model (with a small minority of incompletely identified ones). The grand laundry list is the [particle data booklet](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/tables/contents_tables.html).

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos  ..nice laundry list !   I wonder if there is anyone who actually has a complete grasp of all the particles and all the equations that go into the Standard Model that create all the particles or does it take a team of people just to get to one prediction and yet another team to find them so in the end no one has a complete picture.

Comment: That's what a PhD in physics learns in school....

Comment: thank you for the laundry list...but my guess is a typical PhD scholar will understand a small portion of the whole composite and even that would be more than admirable for a lifetime of work